# Minimal number of squared integers that sums to n - how to do it iteratively?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I am trying to find the minimal number of squared integers that sums to a given number `n`.

I've solved it with recursive function, but I want to do it iteratively.

How to use some loops instead of recursive method?

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> minLen(int n)
    {
        // base case of recursion
        if (n == 0)
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ArrayList<Integer> best = null;
        int bestInt = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i*i <= n; ++i)
        {
            // Check what happens if we use i^2 as part of our representation

            ArrayList<Integer> guess = minLen(n - i*i);
            System.out.println("i:"+i);
            System.out.println("Guess"+guess);
            // If we haven't selected a 'best' yet (best == null)
            // or if our new guess is better than the current choice (guess.size() < best.size())
            // update our choice of best
            if (best == null || guess.size() < best.size())
            {
                best = guess;
                System.out.println("best"+best);

                bestInt = i;
                System.out.println("bestInt"+bestInt);
            }
        }

        best.add(bestInt);
        System.out.println("bestInt"+bestInt);
        System.out.println("best"+best);
        return best;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solves using Dynamic Programming with loops

The problem you are solving is finding the minimal number of squared integers that sums to `n`.

It can be solved in [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) by following the pseudo code:

```
int[] sol = new int[n+1];
//init:
sol[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) sol[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
//fill the value for each i in increasing order:
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++)
   for (int j = 1; j*j <= i; j++)
          //make sure sol[i] contains the best possible solution
          sol[i] = Math.min(sol[i], sol[i-j*j] + 1);
```

The above gives you the minimal possible number (`sol[n]` is the answer), to get the squared number themselves:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
int curr = n;
//while we haven't 'exhausted' the number:
while (curr > 0) { 
    //check all numbers we could have added
    for (int j=1; j*j <= curr ; j++) {
         if found the correct number we used:
         if (sol[curr  - j*j] == sol[curr ] - 1) { 
               //add it to the solution, reduce it from curr and repeat
               numbers.add(j);
               curr = curr - j*j;
               break;
         }
    }
}
```

The idea is to to repeat your steps of the DP solution, and repeat the choices you made along the way.

Comment: I had to change the list to arraylist tats it.      (Type mismatch)                            List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();                    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @Ved It works for me with `List`. Maybe your method's return type is `ArrayList`, and then - you should probably change it to `List<Integer>` instead.